# Minimizing the Determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I would like to minimize the determinant of the following matrix, det(A)

$A = (VV^T+\lambda I)^{-1}$

and $\lambda$ is set to be  very small.

Comment: Min of a **matrix**?

Comment: I edited the text

Comment: What do we know about $V$? What have you tried so far?

Comment: What are the variables over which you are minimizing?

Comment: over V, I would like to minimize det(A) over variable  V

Comment: the size of V is fixed , say N*K

Comment: Ok, then what would be V such that the the largest eigenvalue of A is minimum

Comment: Are there restrictions on $\lambda$? Must it be positive?

Comment: yes, it must be positive

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that $\lambda >0$.

Suppose $V \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, then $V V^T \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$ and has eigenvalues $\sigma_1^2,...,\sigma_m^2$. Hence $V  V^T + \lambda$ has eigenvalues $\sigma_1^2+\lambda,...,\sigma_m^2+\lambda$ and so is invertible, and
since $\det B^{-1} = {1 \over \det B}$, we see that
$\det A = {1 \over \det(V  V^T + \lambda I) } = {1 \over \Pi_{k=1}^m {\sigma_k^2+\lambda}} >0$.

I claim $\inf_V {1 \over \det(V  V^T + \lambda I) }  = 0$.

Note that the largest eigenvalue of $VV^T$ is $\|V\|^2$ (the induced 2-norm of $V$), and so
$0 < {1 \over \det(V  V^T + \lambda I) } = {1 \over \Pi_{k=1}^m {\sigma_k^2+\lambda}} \le {1 \over \|V\|^2+ \lambda} {1 \over \lambda^{m-1}}$. Consequently, if we let $V_k = k E_{11}$ (the matrix with $k$ in the $1,1$ position, and zeros everywhere else) we obtain
$\lim_{k \to \infty} {1 \over \det(V_k  V_k^T + \lambda I) }  = 0$.

Comment: Is there any relation between induced 2-norm and trace operator?

Comment: Can you be more specific? The Frobenius norm is directly related to the trace operator and all norms are equivalent, so the answer is yes, but I'm not sure what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes I know that $\|X\|_F^2$ is equal to $trace(XX^T)$, But you said that the largest eigenvalue of matrix A is equal to its induced 2-norm. Now can I represent the largest eigenvalue of matrix A as $\sqrt{tr(AA^T)}$ ?

Comment: Two things: #1 I had a typo. above which I have corrected (the largest eigenvalue of $A A^T$ is $\|A\|^2$) and #2  you have $\|A\|_2 \le \|A\|_F$. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: well this is an inequality, I am not sure if I am right or not, since my goal is to minimize the largest eigenvalue of a symmetric matrix A, then I only need to minimize the frobenious norm of A which is equal to trace (AA')

Comment: No, minimizing the Frobenius norm is not the same as minimizing the largest eigenvalue. You may want to elaborate your question a little, as is there is no minimum and the infimum is zero.

Comment: Ok, let me explain you my problem. I have a data Matrix $X_{N*M}$, and would like to factorize to matrices U,V such that the product of U and V approximate X. Additionally, I also would like to have a minimum value for the largest eigenvalue of $(V^TV+\lambda I)$.

Comment: You might want to add a new question...